# VBA ListView control misplaced on UserForm inside multipage

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface

I have an user form which contains a multipage control.
The controls are added with the design tool and they look exactly how they should.

The problem appears when I start the form. The first time I switch between pages, the 'main' ListView shows misplaced. After the first switch, everything is displayed as expected.

[image]
[image][image]

Any idea about this?

Comment: You will have to post some code, and pictures of the design forms.

Comment: @RobertBaron The design form is the last picture and it doesn't have any special property. Code should be irrelevant here as it is all in design mode and even empty without loading data the listviews' position is wrong.

Comment: Since everything you do not show is correct, I can only conclude that you have found a bug in MS code. You should report it. In the meantime, just add code to reposition the ListView correctly as a workaround.

Comment: I use this workaround on `initialize` event:    
`mpProgramBlockBookingAdministration.value = 1` and 
    `mpProgramBlockBookingAdministration.value = 0 `

Comment: Ok, but I have no idea what that is or does.

Comment: @RobertBaron Sorry, my bad. It is just the multipage control. I switch to the second page and then back to the first one so it "fixes" the initial misplacement on creation.